# An example of a compact group which its identity connected component is nontrivial, abelian and of measure zero.

Tags: compactness, abelian-groups, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Denote by $G_0$ the identity connected component of a topological group $G$. Is there a **compact** group $G$ such that

1. $G_0$ is abelian group,
2. $Z(G)$ does not contain $G_0$, and
3. $G_0$ is of (Haar) measure zero in $G$?

Comment: say $U(1)\times\mathbb Z_p$? (here $\mathbb Z_p$ are p-adic integers)

Comment: Thank you, but actually I want $G_0$ to be non-central. so I have to edit the question.

Comment: then simply take the semi-direct product of my example above with the 2-element group, wrt. to the action on $U(1)$ by complex conjugation (and trivial action on $\mathbb Z_p$).

Comment: @user8268 thank you so much.